# Adobe Air crash on NetConnection call

Tags: air, crash, amf, netconnection

I have an Adobe Air mobile application that has a NetConnection.  One on call to my AMF server it makes the call and everything returns fine.  When I make a second call my app crashes.

Anyone one run into this?

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need to get more info. Run it in debug mode and you should get a stack trace, variable values and the like.

Comment: Also: get and look at the crash log on the device. May not be helpful, but you won't know until you look :) On that same token, have you looked at the server logs? Is the request hitting the server, is there an error code, yada yada yada.

Comment: Figured it out.  My models in the client and on the server didn't match.  Why AIR just crash and didn't give me an error is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My models in the client and on the server didn't match. Why AIR just crash and didn't give me an error is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server client is the cause of the error!
It may be the reason of automatic combine of the two amf calls by NetConnection.
So, your function on server side will be run twice. 
Check your require or require_one on server side.